# Knn algorithm in golang

Tags: go, knn

### Writing KNN algorithm in golang

Does it make sense? or Is there a package for it?

for exemple in java:

https://github.com/alexksikes/ML/blob/master/knn/kNN.java

Comment: Is this what you are looking for: https://github.com/sjwhitworth/golearn/tree/master/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it makes sense. It depends whether your whole stack is in golang or not. Otherwise, golang doesn't contribute much for ml.

Yes, there are multiple packages for it:

1. https://github.com/sjwhitworth/golearn/tree/master/knn
2. https://github.com/amitkgupta/nearest_neighbour
3. https://github.com/Jragonmiris/knn
4. https://github.com/Akiira/Go-knn
5. https://github.com/CuriousCain/kNN-Iris-set

Some of them you will need to modify. In future for ml need, refer this repo: https://github.com/josephmisiti/awesome-machine-learning